# Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'XrangePointOptionsObject'.ts - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

i'm getting this error on my react highcharts applciation `Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'XrangePointOptionsObject'.ts - React`

[image]

i checked many forum all the answeres are in angular not in react after done lot of research about this i found a link https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13460#issuecomment-627308013 and but i dont know how to impletement in my react-typescript application.

can anyone help me in this.

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that numbers are given where objects of type `XrangePointOptionsObject`are expected. This has nothing to do with angular or REACT.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the series `type` in the series options as mentioned in the API, otherwise TS is not able to validate the options.

```
series: [
  {
    type: "line",
    name: "John",
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
  }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line